# Multiple Relationships to one single UITabbar Item iOS / Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, tabbar

Does anyone know if it is possible for a single tab bar item to have multiple relationships?

I would like to be able to direct to two different view controllers from a single UITabbar icon, depending on the type of user that logs in.

For example, if the user logs in as user type "A", I want the Tab bar icon to direct to a profile view controller. If the user logs in as user type "B", I want the same icon to direct to a settings view controller.

I've tried to connect the additional view controller to the tab bar and it  just creates an additional icon/tab on the tab bar.

Comment: Are you trying to achieve this purely using Storyboards? Or are you setting up your tab bar in applicationDidFinish launching method of your app delegate? Also, by tab bar icon, do you mean, tapping on the tab while showing the same icon for users who are type A or type B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do it from code, so look at the `setViewControllers` method.

Supposing you have 4 Tabs corresponding to `vc1` `vc2` `vc A or B` and `vc4`...

You could determine which VC you want assigned, then instantiate the full "set" of controllers with:

```
// set "vcA" as the 3rd tab
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:@[vc1, vc2, vcA, vc4] animated:NO];

// or, set "vcB" as the 3rd tab
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:@[vc1, vc2, vcB, vc4] animated:NO];
```

Or... to save on "manually" instantiating the controllers...

You could assign all 5 controllers in your storyboard, then:

```
// get the array of viewControllers
NSMutableArray *a = self.tabBarController.viewControllers;

// a now contains  [vc1, vc2, vcA, vcB, vc4]

// remove "vcA"
[a removeObjectAtIndex:2];

// or, remove "vcB"
[a removeObjectAtIndex:3];

// set the controllers array
[self.tabBarController setViewControllers:a animated:NO];
```

Comment: Thank you, DonMag! This worked well. In your second solution I just needed to make sure that self.tabBarController.viewControllers is mutable since it's originally an NSArray. I did that like this: NSMutableArray *a = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers mutableCopy];

Answer (score 0):

You could also place a container view in the the view controller for that tab, add two views to the container view, and then depending on what type of user it is show the proper view during `viewDidLoad`.

Will add code when I have time.

Answer (score 0):

This would be one way of doing it:

A. keep track of what sort of user logs in held a variable, passed on from your previous viewController, or held centrally in a data object:

```
bool userCanAccessProfile = false;
```

B. depending on the above bool, update your layout and logic code accordingly:

```
//layout your tab bar
UITabBar * tabBar = [UITabBar new];
tabBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, h-50, w, 50);
tabBar.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:tabBar];

//create the item(s)
UITabBarItem * item = [UITabBarItem new];
item.title = (userCanAccessProfile) ? @"Profile" : @"Settings";
item.image = (userCanAccessProfile) ? [UIImage imageNamed:@"profile.png"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"settings.png"];
[tabBar setItems:@[item]];
```

The lines above that look like this, means this:

```
something = (isThisTrue) ? (true) setThisValue : (false) setAnotherValue;
```

You're asking if userCanAccessProfile is true, and if it is, you're setting a different text and image accordingly.

C. When the User clicks on the item, you would again query the bool to find out what to do:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item {

    //when the item is clicked
    if (userCanAccessProfile){

        //open profile

    } else {

        //open settings
    }
}
```

Be sure to set the delegate in the .m file:

```
tabBar.delegate = self;
```

and add the delegate in the .h file:

```
@interface yourVC : UIViewController <UITabBarDelegate>
```